# Table View hidden behind large gray box

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a table view that was properly displaying using the Basic layout. After creating a custom cell, almost the entire table view is now covered by a large gray area. When I click the Add bar button, the table displays the cells properly for a second while the segue switches into the add item view controller. Also, when pressing Cancel from the add item view controller, the table displays properly for a second as it segues back, but then is covered by the gray box again.

Here is my custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPhone: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDetail: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

I didn't change anything in the TableViewController other than casting the cell as the custom cell class. What am I missing?

PS: I'm using Xcode 6, Beta 5

Comment: Extra view in your storyboard that you were using while laying out the app, that you forgot about?

Comment: Only 2 views- the TVC and the VC. The TVC has a nav controller. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could your custom cell be larger than the rows in your table View?  Try setting the row height in the tableviewdatasource and/or then on the custom cell say self.layer.clipsToBounds=true

Comment: Changing the row height in the view controller did the trick. i didn't have to use the line of code you mentioned. Thanks